# Installing Rails on RaspberryPi (Raspbian Buster) fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am still quite new to Rails(1). 
Yesterday, I installed Ruby on Rails on a RaspberryPi (with a pristine SD card and fresh etched OS) the Debian way: 
`sudo apt-get install ruby rails` 
This (seemingly) successfully installed me Rails (version 5.2.2.1) and Ruby (version 2.5.5p157) and I created a new application framework without trouble. However, starting the puma server just results in a long error log. 
`bundle update` 
 aborts at 
`installing Nokogiri 1.10.4 (was 1.10.0)` 
(... can't find headerr files for Ruby'...). 
Not surprisingly, the server still responds with just the same error messages.
 
Any help in getting things up and running is highly appreciated.
Thanks! 
Karsten

 
(1) I am absolutely sure, I am not the first and only with this question. Three weeks ago I had about the same difficulties with the installation procedure at my laptop running plain Debian. I searched for about two days without finding clear guidance (ok, not smart enough ;-). Finally I managed to get things running by manually setting GEMS versions to the pre-installed values. However, this took quite some time and because I am new, I am unaware which implications my trial-and-error settings have. Because I did not log my actions, now I would need to restart the procedure from scratch... There must be a better approach ==> sorry for redundant postings.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the headers files for ruby:

`sudo apt-get install ruby-dev`

Comment: Thanks thaleshcv!! Installing the dev files helped for having the bundler running smoothely. The crash of the puma server, however, persists. But this is another topic.